# In Java, does read only access to Strings need to be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Is it required to synchronize read only access to Strings in Java?

Comment: Feel free to accept some more of your answers.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with read only access? Could you post some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Strings are immutable. If all you're doing is reading the String, you're absolutely fine.

Edit to add: Yes, if you have a mutable property, that changing the value of the property would need to be synchronized.

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate, the reference to the `String` needs to be `final` as well to make it completely thread safe.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson While generally true in a read-only (assuming he means the reference to the string with read-only - not that anything else makes much sense here) scenario that's also unimportant. Though since read-only is basically final, better to make it explicit.

Comment: you can't make the reference to an index `final`

Comment: @Ishtar `private final String s = "Hello World!";` is perfectly thread safe in all conditions.

Comment: `String` is immutable, its internal state is always thread safe, I specifically state that the reference needs to be `final` to be 100% thread safe. How can you mis-interpret that?

Answer (score 10):

Immutable objects like `String` are thread safe, in that their **internal** state will never change, and `final` references to those `String` objects are thread safe.

**But**, if you have a **non-final** reference to an immutable object, **it isn't completely thread safe.**

Given :

```
public final String x = "This reference is thread safe, it can never change";
```

any references to `x` are thread safe since what `x` refers to can never change and the `String` object is **immutable**.

And given :

```
public String s = "This reference is not thread safe, it can change";
```

any references to `s` are **not** thread safe, because `s` can possibly change to something else. That is :

```
s = "this is another different immutable String";
```

can change what `s` refers to. If your references should never change make them `final` if they are expected to change you should declare them `volatile` so the JVM knows to re-read the contents of the reference and not do any caching optomizations that might miss changes to `s`.

```
public volatile String s = "This reference is expected to change, so tell the JVM";
```

See [The final word on final](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/05/the-final-word-on-final/) for more information on thread safety and the `final` keyword.

Answer (score 4):

Not for a `String`, per se, but for the reference to a `String`, definitely.

Edit:

The references of variables that are not declared as final (or otherwise synchronized) are not guaranteed to be seen by all threads. While it is safe for many threads to read the value of the same `String` object, you need to somehow guarantee that all threads are reading the most up to date reference.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? An example could help a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable objects and therefore thread-safe in themselves.  Note that a function like String.toUpperCase() does not change the String object itself but returns a new String.

StringBuffer and StringBuilder are mutable objects.  StringBuffer is thread-safe and StringBuilder is not.

Answer (score 1):

Every String access is *read only* (Strings are immutable) and because the content of a `String` instance can't change, there's no need to synchronize.