# Is String get/set threadsafe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, immutability

Let's say I have the following,

```
public class Foo{
    private String bar;

    public String getBar(){
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar){
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Are these methods automatically threadsafe due to the immutable nature of the `String` class, or is some locking mechanism required?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `String` in the setter.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis, Yes, my mistake! Fixed.

Comment: Related c# question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595114/why-are-immutable-objects-thread-safe

Comment: A String object is, a non-final reference to it isn't. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6060405/1812922 for more details

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, this is not threadsafe. `Foo` is mutable, so if you want to ensure that different threads see the same value of `bar` – that is, **consistency** – either:

- Make `bar` `volatile`, or
- Make the methods `synchronized`, or
- Use an `AtomicReference<String>`.

The reads and writes of `bar` are themselves atomic, but atomicity is not thread safety.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

---

For in-depth coverage of Java concurrency, grab a copy of [Java Concurrency in Practice (aka JCIP)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).

Comment: +1 Or simply declare `bar` as `final`, so the reference cannot be re-assigned to another value. Of course, there will be no setter then :)

Comment: That's immutable.  No need for a setter in that case. And you have to be sure to supply a constructor to initialize the value, because you can't change it once you exit the constructor in that case.

Comment: ... Out of curiosity, do either of those actually matter?  I mean, if your actual problem is a race condition, that can still happen, despite the `volatile` or `synchronized` - it just decreases the 'window' in which it can happen, right?  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse and what race condition would that be? TBH, questions like these are why I avoid sharing mutable (non-concurrent-library) objects across threads as much as possible.

Comment: Thread one is updating `bar` continuously.  Thread two is waiting for `bar` to read as some value (just spinning with a `while(...)` loop, say).  The race condition is for thread two to read the value of `bar` before thread one updates it again.  While either of those options make it so that all threads are guaranteed to have the same internal reference (although references are atomic _regardless_), that doesn't matter if they're working on the object at different time-slices.  And yeah, stuff like this is why I prefer immutable objects.

Comment: @Matt Ball if instead String field was mutable, then volatile was not make class thread safe?

Answer (score 7):

You're setting references, and as such `String`'s immutability doesn't come into play. You're not affecting the contents of `String`.

Answer (score 5):

No, not safe.

This is Foo mutable behavior; String's immutability does not accrue to Foo.

```
public class Foo{
    private String bar;

    public synchronized String getBar(){
        return bar;
    }

    public synchronized void setBar(String bar){
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 What about synchronizing `getBar()`? Maybe some thread setting a new value to `bar`, while the other threads reading `bar`.

Comment: Sorry, you're making no sense to me.  I think your comments are only confusing the issue.

Comment: @duffymo does a non-synchronized getter with a synchronized setter guarantee consistency across threads?

Comment: @duffymo as you have it now, the getter needs to be synchronized to ensure that `bar`'s current state is visible to all threads

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not thread safe.

While `String` is immutable, the issue comes from the field of `Foo`. To make this more apparent, consider for example a method whose job would be to *append* (rather than replace) the value of `bar`. When it's called from multiple threads, some writes could be lost. The same (lost writes) can happen with your simple setter too, even if it's not obvious initially in this case.